# Having issues calling a variable thoughout a program c#

Tags: c#, variables, global-variables, call

I think this is very simple but I am confused on how to set the variable "result" (see the code below) so I can call it later on in the program when I want the timer to display the current RAM usage divided by the total RAM installed to gather a usage percent. The way WMI gathers the installed RAM has been throwing me off as it has to do result["TotalVisibleMemorySize"]. The issue with having the whole block of code in the timer is that it refreshes every 2 seconds which would really lag up the counter since WMI is slow. Thanks!

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ObjectQuery wql = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wql);
        ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject result in results)
        {                
             label1.Text = Convert.ToInt32(result["TotalVisibleMemorySize"]) + " KB";               
        }
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = (int)(performanceCounter1.NextValue() - Convert.ToInt32(result["TotalVisibleMemorySize"]));
        label1.Text = "Processor Time: " + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";                          
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your results variable is in your Form1_Load method.

You'd need to move it outside that scope, either as a member of Form1, or a global (like in Program.cs.)

I'd recommend NOT doing a global, but creating a private variable like:

```
public class Form1
{
    private ManagementObjectCollection results;
... rest of code
}
```

Then when you need to, in other places in your Form1 class you could use the `results.Whatever`

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to declare private variable inside the class:

```
private int _totalMemory = 0;

// And in your form load event.
_totalMemory = Convert.ToInt32(result["TotalVisibleMemorySize"])

// And in your timer tick event.
progressBar1.Value = (int)(performanceCounter1.NextValue() - _totalMemory);
```